# Jersey WebResource URL pathing issues

Tags: java, jersey

I am having an issue with generating a location resource using the Jersey API and a simple client.

I am trying to call a REST service which returns JSON.

Here is the code which configures the client and prints out the request URL.

```
public class ServiceCaller {

    //Hiding actual key for purpose of question
    private static final String API_KEY = "...";

    private static final String BASE_URI = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/";     
    private static final String SUMMONER_BY_NAME = "v1.4/summoner/by-name/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String summonerName = "Bob";
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);

        System.out.println("Service Request: " + summonerName);
        WebResource locationResource = resource.path(SUMMONER_BY_NAME + URLEncoder.encode(summonerName, "UTF-8")  + "?api_key=" + API_KEY);
        System.out.println(locationResource);
        "\n");
    }
```

It prints this: `https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Bob%3Fapi_key=...`

But I am expecting this: `https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Bob?api_key=...`

It somehow replaces the hardcoded ?api_key= string with %3api_key=

Does anyone see what I am overlooking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebResource, I think you can use the MultivaluedMap to add query params for you:

```
MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("param1", "val1");
queryParams.add("param2", "val2");
String s = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
```

Reference:
https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with

Hope this helps,
Matt